# What writing utensil should I use on gaming paper?

Tags: tools, battle-map

I have recently bought some [gaming paper](https://www.miniaturemarket.com/ggp0001.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_aTo-P-z1QIV0ISzCh0bgwdBEAYYASABEgJGqfD_BwE). This is a specific product that's supposed to be reusable, and might not be the same as other products with the "gaming paper name".

What should I be using to write on it? I tested dry erase markers, and they didn't work. Do I need to laminate it?

Answer (score 16):

You should have a look at the [manufacturer's FAQ](http://gamingpaper.com/faqs/). It does appear to have a coating on it, and they recommend using color pencils for things you want to remove.

Answer (score 5):

Gaming paper is disposable. Use anything on it that you would use on regular paper (like ballpoint pen). Instead of erasing large portions of drawing, you throw it away and use a new sheet.

From [a Q&A for this product on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003G4DLLC):

> **Question:** Can you use wet dry markers on this? Does it wipe off as I saw it has a wax like surface
>
> **Answer** [from the manufacturer]: No, it is permanent. Works best with sharpies. Best option for drawing up your maps and bringing them to the game. Also great for mapping locations where the players may return.

Comment: Derek, the URL from the OP suggests that it is "reusable" as well as disposable.

Comment: It's reusable like notebook paper is reusable.

Comment: This now appears to be a different product than the one with the Q&A you posted from Amazon.

Comment: @ZeissIkon SKU GGP-0001 in both cases. It is the exact same product.

Comment: I added a link to the Q&A on the product page, so readers can verify that it is indeed the product being asked about.

Answer (score 5):

I’ve seen this sort of ‘paper’ written on with china markers and crayons, with reasonably good results. Don't bear down too hard, only just hard enough to make clear marks, because when you’re using these implements, the harder you bear down in writing, the harder you’ll have to rub to erase later.

For cleaning the residue, as an alternative to the window cleaner suggested by @ZeissIkon (which is a good suggestion), a mild detergent - dishwashing liquid or shampoo, for example - can be helpful. But you’ll still have to rub a bit.

Comment: This works, too -- and window cleaner can also help in taking the wax residue off the gaming paper.

Answer (score 3):

I have something similar (but more expensive, so YMMV) that I write on with ***wet erase*** markers.  These wipe off with a slightly damp paper towel.  You should be able to pick these up at an office supply store or some big box stores.

Answer (score 0):

I used a very similar product many years ago (early to mid 1980s) with water color markers.  They wipe off easily with a damp cloth or paper towel, are inexpensive, and come in a wide variety of colors.  When they start to show an overall cast from color that hasn't come off with plain water, small amount of window cleaner will improve the clarity of the surface.

Write only on the glossy (plastic coated) side.

Comment: I don't think this product has a glossy side.

Comment: @DerekStucki - [The picture that the question linked to](https://www.miniaturemarket.com/ggp0001.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_aTo-P-z1QIV0ISzCh0bgwdBEAYYASABEgJGqfD_BwE) suggests that it does.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am talking about the exact same product, but it looks very similar.

My gaming group uses [non-permanent markers](https://www.staedtler.co.uk/en/products/markers-refill-ink/universal-pens/lumocolor-non-permanent-pen-311-non-permanent-universal-pen-s/#id=14285&tx_solr[q]=lumocolor%20non%20permanent) which are easy to erase with a wet sponge or wet paper towel.

Yesterday evening we tried dry eraser markers and it was very hard to remove (finally managed to get it off by rubbing with a hard sponge, damaging a bit the original square marking, different cleaning products didn't help at all).